# ReadonlySpan As Property

Tags: c#, .net-core

I try to understand .net core 3.0.
As far as i know, i cannot use Span or ReadonlySpan as properties or members since it is stack based struct.
And I want to know the differences between the following definition.
I can successfully define 'part1' without any error.
I received the following compile error for part2 
"A result of a stackalloc expression of type Span cannot be used in this context"
For part3, i received the different compile error.
"Field or auto-implemented property cannot be type ReadonlySpan"

```
public class KeyGenWithSpan
{
   private static ReadOnlySpan<char> part1 => new[] { 'p', '1'};
   private static ReadOnlySpan<char> part2 => stackalloc[]{'1','2'};
   private static ReadOnlySpan<char> part3 = stackalloc[]{'1','2'};
}
```

Comment: pedantic point, perhaps, but spans are not specific to .NET Core 3; they are back-ported to a lot more frameworks (although the implementation is *better* on .NET Core 3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *span* is a stack-based struct, but the *data* can be *anywhere*. It could be in  an array, it could be unmanaged memory, it could be the stack, it could be a "fixed buffer", or a string, etc.

You *can* have spans as properties. What you *can't* have is spans as *fields*, except on `ref struct` types. The property would act as a *proxy* to get the span *from something* (perhaps an array).

In `part1`, you're allocating a **new array every time**, but that isn't necessary - it can be done smarter.

This however, is not possible for `stackalloc`, since `stackalloc` would allocate *in the property getter's stack-frame*, which no longer exists when you exit the getter.

Consider:

```cs
private static readonly char[] s_data = { 'p', '1'};
public static ReadOnlySpan<char> Data => s_data; // perfectly valid conversion
```

---

Note that *for some types* (notably: not `char`), the compiler can do extra voodoo here:

```cs
public static ReadOnlySpan<byte> Data2 => new byte[] { 0, 1 };
```

does *not* compile to a new array each time in the getter; instead, it draws directly from the assembly metadata:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static valuetype [System.Runtime]System.ReadOnlySpan`1<uint8> get_Data2() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldsflda int16 <PrivateImplementationDetails>::3F29546453678B855931C174A97D6C0894B8F546
    L_0005: ldc.i4.2 
    L_0006: newobj instance void [System.Runtime]System.ReadOnlySpan`1<uint8>::.ctor(void*, int32)
    L_000b: ret 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to create a ReadonlySpan property is by using the AsSpan method to create an expression-bodied property directly from a string literal. For example:

```
private static ReadOnlySpan<char> BeginSpan => "^".AsSpan();
private static ReadOnlySpan<char> EndSpan => "$".AsSpan();
```